# Spring Framework, Spring Security - possible to use Spring Security without Spring Framework?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-security, aop

Ive been working now with the Spring Framework 3.0.5 and Spring Security 3.0.5 for several time. I know that Spring Framework uses DI and AOP. I also know that Spring Security uses DI, for example when writing custom handlers or filters. Im not sure whether Spring Security also uses AOP - so my first question is: does it?

Well, Id also like to know how Spring Security can be used for non-spring-based applications. Its written in their documentation that this is possible. Well, I wonder how - it seems like it uses DI, so how should it work in a simple java web application? I guess at least a web container which supports dependency injection is needed, correct? (Which one could that be?)

Thank you for answering :-)

[EDIT]
documentation says:

> "documentation says: "Spring Security provides comprehensive security services for J2EE-based enterprise software applications. There is a particular emphasis on supporting projects built using The Spring Framework, which is the leading J2EE solution for enterprise software development. If you're not using Spring for developing enterprise applications, we warmly encourage you to take a closer look at it. Some familiarity with Spring - and in particular dependency injection principles - will help you get up to speed with Spring Security more easily.""

j2ee-based enterprise software applications......... emphasis on supporting projects using spring framework...... well this means it should be possible to work with it without Spring Framework itself!
?

AND:

> Even though we use Spring to configure Spring Seurity, your application doesn't have to be Spring-based. Many people use Spring Security with web frameworks such as Struts, for example.

This is from the spring security homepage. well....

Comment: You asked 'so how should it work in a simple java application?', you mean a simple web application ? If not then you should not be using spring security as its a web security framework. So yes you will need at least a servlet specification compliant container.

Comment: yes, of course I meant simple java WEB application, sorry ;-) of course I will need a servlet container - sure. but it does have to support dependency injection, doesnt it?

Comment: there are containers that don't support DI ? No you don't need a j2ee container. I'm currently using it with tomcat. Also yes you don't need to be spring-based (for instance spring MVC), but you still need to define some beans (most likely) which would not make you spring based :)

Comment: I'm also currently using Struts + Spring security and this particular project is not spring based (its struts + ejb3), spring is only used for security related beans.

Comment: As a minimum you just need a servlet container and spring dependencies. Other technologies are not enforced.

Comment: ok. so Spring Security can be used WITHOUT the Spring Framework? What do you mean with spring dependencies? spring core librarys? :) Thanks for your answer. Maybe you should update then your first answer, because I understood that generally one cant use spring security without spring...

Comment: What do you mean by Spring Framework ? :) You need spring's DI only to use spring security, nothing else, this is what I meant in my answer. I'll edit it and you're welcome :)

Comment: with Spring Framework I meant the librarys of (for example) Spring Framework 3.0.5. I looked at your link in your posting, I couldnt find them, but a library namend spring.jar, which I dont know. Is this one always needed? Can it be replaced by ones of the Spring Framework 3.0.5? Thank you! :-)

Comment: the spring.jar was renamed to spring-core in 3.0.5. So yes it can be replaced. You can download the security sample app here: http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/sample-apps.html and look at the libraries it is using and you'll find out exactly what is needed for spring-security.

Comment: thank you so much for your patience! so, for using spring security, spring-core is needed! I for myself think then that the documentation is somehow wrong verbalised. spring-based for me means using spring-core. not spring-based would not be using spring-core. thats obviously wrong then

Comment: yes the spring-security docs can definably be better IMO :) I think that by spring-based they meant an application that will not work without spring, which would be an app that uses Spring MVC for instance

Comment: yes, that must be what they meant. thank you! :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does it use AOP ?

Yes spring-security uses AOP for its [method security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/ns-config.html) (you'd have to search the page to find it).

> Can you use spring-security without spring ?

Generally no.

As you need to define spring beans for several spring-security elements.

**But**! You can use [Acegi security](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?61764-Spring-Security-Without-Spring) without spring as far as I know. Which should give you close to the same functionality.

> Can you secure a non-J2EE application

Definitely.

Anything that can run in a servlet container can be secured with spring-security. You just need Spring's IoC/DI.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6345354/cannot-integrate-spring-security-basic-authentication-into-jersey-jax-rs-and-tomc/6345609#6345609) answer can help you on the minimal spring-security dependencies.

Comment: thanks for your answer. please take a look at my changes in my posting. there they say its used for securing j2ee-based enterprise software applications..... which means its not only for the spring framework....

Comment: @nano7 if you're worried about using a j2ee container, no you don't need it you just need a servlet container, I'm currently using it in Tomcat without any j2ee stack related technology.

Comment: this is now totally confusing me. why does the documentation then say, that spring security is for "securing j2ee applications"? they can but must not be spring-based. uff.

Comment: @nano7 yes exactly, they can be spring-based, but its not mandatory.